# How to fetch data from two different tables using between statement?

Tags: php, mysqli-multi-query

here Iam trying to fetch two table data based on one column 'createdon' and my statement is like below

```
"SELECT * FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.createdon = table2.createdon WHERE table1.createdon AND table2.createdon BETWEEN '$fromdate' AND '$todate' ORDER BY id"
```

would anyone correct me please, if Iam wrong

Thanks you......

Comment: What does this have to do with `mysqli_multi_query()`? That's for executing two queries in one call, not for querying two tables.

Answer (score -1):

you shouldn't say `table1.createdon AND table2.createdon`. You only need to test one of them, since the `ON` condition requires both rows to have the same `createdon` value.

```
"SELECT * 
FROM table1 
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.createdon = table2.createdon 
WHERE table1.createdon BETWEEN '$fromdate' AND '$todate'
ORDER BY id"
```